# android inapp purchase lib not found in eclipse

Tags: java, android, in-app

I am trying out to implement in-app purchase in my android app for the first time. After lots of research I found a tutorial for it.

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/documentation/environment-setup.html#Prerequisites

However, as mentioned in the tutorial, the in-app-purchasing lib is located in /In-App-Purchasing/lib , which I am unable to find. There is no In-app-purchasing folder in my sdk path. Do I have to download this lib file and add to my folder? Please guide. Also suggest if there is a better tutorial for in-app purchase implementation.

Comment: Have you downloaded the jar file???

Comment: No. From where do I download the jar file?

Comment: Please look at this link and download Amazon Mobile App SDK  and follow this link https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/eclipse-plugin.html

Comment: You can accept the answer if you feel its helped you thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow [The Amazon Mobile App SDK Eclipse Plugin](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/eclipse-plugin.html) the described link. And follow steps for setting Amazon Mobile App SDK with Android SDK eclipse.